# Pytesseract-OCR wrong japanese detection

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

I installed Pystesseract 5.0 from [Here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) and marked the Japanese language during installation.
It is not correctly detecting Japanese letters.
Note: the same code is detecting English characters alright.

Here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
#################################################################################################


# Read your file
file = 'removed.png'
img = cv2.imread(file, 0)
img.shape

# thresholding the image to a binary image
thresh, img_bin = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# inverting the image
img_bin = 255 - img_bin

# Plotting the image to see the output
plotting = plt.imshow(img_bin, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# Define a kernel to detect rectangular boxes

# Length(width) of kernel as 100th of total width
kernel_len = np.array(img).shape[1] // 100
# Defining a vertical kernel to detect all vertical lines of image
ver_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_len))
# Defining a horizontal kernel to detect all horizontal lines of image
hor_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_len, 1))
# A kernel of 2x2
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))

#### Vertical LINES ####
# Use vertical kernel to detect and save the vertical lines in a jpg
image_1 = cv2.erode(img_bin, ver_kernel, iterations=5)
vertical_lines = cv2.dilate(image_1, ver_kernel, iterations=45)
# Plot the generated image
plotting = plt.imshow(image_1, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

#### HORTIZONAL LINES ####
# Use horizontal kernel to detect and save the horizontal lines in a jpg
image_2 = cv2.erode(img_bin, hor_kernel, iterations=5)
horizontal_lines = cv2.dilate(image_2, hor_kernel, iterations=45)
# Plot the generated image
plotting = plt.imshow(image_2, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# Combining both H and V
# Combine horizontal and vertical lines in a new third image, with both having same weight.
img_vh = cv2.addWeighted(vertical_lines, 0.5, horizontal_lines, 0.5, 0.0)
# Eroding and thesholding the image
img_vh = cv2.erode(~img_vh, kernel, iterations=1)
thresh, img_vh = cv2.threshold(img_vh, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plotting = plt.imshow(img_vh, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

##
bitxor = cv2.bitwise_xor(img, img_vh)
bitnot = cv2.bitwise_not(bitxor)
# Plotting the generated image
plotting = plt.imshow(bitnot, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
# Detect contours for following box detection
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_vh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0
    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True
    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1
    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
                                        key=lambda b: b[1][i], reverse=reverse))
    # return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
    return (cnts, boundingBoxes)


# Sort all the contours by top to bottom.
contours, boundingBoxes = sort_contours(contours, method="bottom-to-top")
################
# Creating a list of heights for all detected boxes
heights = [boundingBoxes[i][3] for i in range(len(boundingBoxes))]
# Get mean of heights
mean = np.mean(heights)

# Create list box to store all boxes in
box = []
# Get position (x,y), width and height for every contour and show the contour on image
for c in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if (w > 110 and h < 85):
        image = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        box.append([x, y, w, h])
plotting = plt.imshow(image, cmap="cividis")
plt.show()

# Creating two lists to define row and column in which cell is located
row = []
column = []
j = 0

# Sorting the boxes to their respective row and column
for i in range(len(box)):
    if (i == 0):
        column.append(box[i])
        previous = box[i]
    else:
        if (box[i][1] <= previous[1] + mean / 2):
            column.append(box[i])
            previous = box[i]
            if (i == len(box) - 1):
                row.append(column)
        else:
            row.append(column)
            column = []
            previous = box[i]
            column.append(box[i])
print("Columns:", column)
print("Rows: ", row)

# calculating maximum number of cells
countcol = 0
for i in range(len(row)):
    countcol = len(row[i])
    if countcol > countcol:
        countcol = countcol
print("Max cells: ", countcol)

# Retrieving the center of each column
center = [int(row[i][j][0] + row[i][j][2] / 2) for j in range(len(row[i])) if row[0]]
center = np.array(center)
center.sort()

# Regarding the distance to the columns center, the boxes are arranged in respective order
finalboxes = []
for i in range(len(row)):
    lis = []
    for k in range(countcol):
        lis.append([])
    for j in range(len(row[i])):
        diff = abs(center - (row[i][j][0] + row[i][j][2] / 4))
        minimum = min(diff)
        indexing = list(diff).index(minimum)
        lis[indexing].append(row[i][j])
    finalboxes.append(lis)

# from every single image-based cell/box the strings are extracted via pytesseract and stored in a list
outer = []
for i in range(len(finalboxes)):
    for j in range(len(finalboxes[i])):
        inner = ''
        if (len(finalboxes[i][j]) == 0):
            outer.append(' ')
        else:
            for k in range(len(finalboxes[i][j])):
                y, x, w, h = finalboxes[i][j][k][0], finalboxes[i][j][k][1], finalboxes[i][j][k][2], \
                             finalboxes[i][j][k][3]
                finalimg = bitnot[x:x + h, y:y + w]
                kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 1))
                border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(finalimg, 2, 2, 2, 2, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[255, 255])
                resizing = cv2.resize(border, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                dilation = cv2.dilate(resizing, kernel, iterations=1)
                erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations=1)

                out = pytesseract.image_to_string(erosion)
                if (len(out) == 0):
                    out = pytesseract.image_to_string(erosion, config='--psm 3')
                inner = inner + " " + out
            outer.append(inner)
##Printing all detected cells 
for element in outer:
    if len(element) > 10:
        for line in element.splitlines():
            if len(line)>2:
                print("##", line.strip())
```

And here is the output for the last segment of code:

```
## LotNo. |
## fo
## 900-1829-B
## 2021/09/17
## 1, 000
## Wes FE —Cu-ESEIRNI
## LCH2
## 4X17. 05
## TYYY GISA-5AIB
## /448642-2 B
```

As you can see it is finding difficulty detecting japanese letters

Comment: reduce code to few lines only with `Pytesseract` and image.

Comment: maybe it needs to add Japanes as parameter when you run `Pytesseract` because installing doesn't means it will use it - as default it may use only English.

Comment: you can test it directly in console using `tesseract.exe image.png output.txt -l jap+eng`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tesseract` as default uses only `English` and you may have to set other language(s) as parameter.

At console you can test it as

```
tesseract.exe image.png output.txt -l jpn
```

or even with many languages

```
tesseract.exe image.png output.txt -l jpn+eng
```

(instead of `output.txt` you can use `-` to display text directly in console)

---

In code it can be

```
pytesseract.image_to_string('image.png', config='-l jpn')

pytesseract.image_to_string('image.png', config='-l jpn+eng')
```

or

```
pytesseract.image_to_string('image.png', lang='jpn')

pytesseract.image_to_string('image.png', lang='jpn+eng')
```